# How to switch between chat windows in Kadu?

Tags: shortcut-keys

Ctrl+Tab doesnt work, Windows+Tab doesnt work as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its in configuration

> move left tab - Ctrl+Shift+Left
>
> move right right - Ctrl+Shift+Right